# I am new to App devekopment. I was trying to make a wishList app. In that app when I implemented delete function my app is crashing

Tags: android, kotlin, user-interface, debugging, roomdb

While make swipe to delete feature for my app, I faced a problem that if there are two or more that two wishes and I swipe to delete a wish , my app gets closed. Even though that wish will get deleted. But closing of app problem is occuring. And one more thing, if there is only one wish and I swipe to delete it. Then no problem is occuring. Please help to solve the problem.

I had tried these pieces of codes but the problem is there. If you need any other piece of code please let me know. Since I am new to app development I also don't know how to debug it so I hadn't debug it.
Code of Home View file

[text](https://pl.kotl.in/aoH0nu7Ho)
Code for Wish View Model where delete function is there
[text](https://pl.kotl.in/m_57r6pkJ)

Code for Wish Repository and wish Dao

[text](https://pl.kotl.in/kT_cmKmSA)
[text](https://pl.kotl.in/HY7n5MchT)
Please help me to solve the problem.

I had tried all the methods and code is shared in the form of link.

Comment: Please note that you should include your code and any errors as text and not as links.  Links tend to become obsolete making your question very contextless.